# How do I solve a ValueError when using bag of words?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, spacy, valueerror

I am using bag of words and ran into a 'ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index.'

I'm following documentation that I used successfully on a previous project, but this time I am getting an error. I printed the following values after getting the error: len(sentences) = 13680; len(comedy_common_words) = 4675.

````
def bag_of_words(text):

        allwords = [token.lemma_
                    for token in text
                    if not token.is_punct
                    and not token.is_stop]

        return [item[0] for item in Counter(allwords).most_common(2000)

def bow_features(sentences, comedy_common_words):

        df = pd.DataFrame(columns=comedy_common_words)
        df['text_sentence'] = sentences[0]
        df['text_source'] = sentences[1]
        df.loc[:, comedy_common_words] = 0

        for i, sentence in enumerate(df['text_sentence']):

            words = [token.lemma_
                     for token in sentence
                     if (
                         not token.is_punct
                         and not token.is_stop
                         and token.lemma_ in comedy_common_words
                     )]

            for word in words:
                df.loc[i, word] += 1

            if i % 50 == 0:
                print("Processing row{}".format(i))

        return df

much_ado_words = bag_of_words(much_ado_doc)
midsummer_words = bag_of_words(midsummer_doc)
twelfth_words = bag_of_words(twelfth_doc)
merchant_words = bag_of_words(merchant_doc)

comedy_common_words = set(much_ado_words + midsummer_words + 
        twelfth_words + merchant_words)```
````

comedy_word_counts = bow_features(sentences, comedy_common_words)
comedy_word_counts.head()```

Expected bag of words to iterate through and return a data frame with comedy_common_words as the columns and sentences as the rows. Instead received:

```
ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-3f3cba5f1f1d> in <module>
      1 # Create our data frame with features. This can take a while to run.
----> 2 comedy_word_counts = bow_features(sentences, comedy_common_words)
      3 comedy_word_counts.head()

<ipython-input-24-57bed1524659> in bow_features(sentences, comedy_common_words)
     18     df = pd.DataFrame(columns=comedy_common_words)
     19     df['text_sentence'] = sentences[0]
---> 20     df['text_source'] = sentences[1]
     21     df.loc[:, comedy_common_words] = 0
     22 

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   3368         else:
   3369             # set column
-> 3370             self._set_item(key, value)
   3371 
   3372     def _setitem_slice(self, key, value):

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _set_item(self, key, value)
   3443 
   3444         self._ensure_valid_index(value)
-> 3445         value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
   3446         NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
   3447 

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _sanitize_column(self, key, value, broadcast)
   3628 
   3629             # turn me into an ndarray
-> 3630             value = sanitize_index(value, self.index, copy=False)
   3631             if not isinstance(value, (np.ndarray, Index)):
   3632                 if isinstance(value, list) and len(value) > 0:

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in sanitize_index(data, index, copy)
    517 
    518     if len(data) != len(index):
--> 519         raise ValueError('Length of values does not match length of index')
    520 
    521     if isinstance(data, ABCIndexClass) and not copy:

ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Comment: which line of code makes problem ?

Comment: ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-3f3cba5f1f1d> in <module>
      1 # Create our data frame with features. This can take a while to run.
----> 2 comedy_word_counts = bow_features(sentences, comedy_common_words)
      3 comedy_word_counts.head()

<ipython-input-24-57bed1524659> in bow_features(sentences, comedy_common_words)
     18     df = pd.DataFrame(columns=comedy_common_words)
     19     df['text_sentence'] = sentences[0]
---> 20     df['text_source'] = sentences[1]
     21     df.loc[:, comedy_common_words] = 0

Comment: always put error in question, not in comment. There will be more readable. And other peopel will see it. People may not read comments.